# Best way to inject HTML into a page (server-side) in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, httphandler, server-side

I've got a HTTPHandler which returns a lump of HTML. What's the best way to inject this into a control on the server?

I've got it mostly working by using an asp:literal and using WebClient.downloadString() to grab the text from the handler

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Text_Page1" Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Text_Page2" Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
```

and then in the server-side methods:

```
Text_Page1.Text = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://localhost:666/" +sPage1URL);
Text_Page2.Text = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://localhost:666/" +sPage2URL);
```

The hardcoded web-address is just there for testing at the moment. Previously I tried just using "~/" +URL to try and build it up but the WebClient library threw an exception saying that the URL was too long (which is not true I don't think)

Any ideas on the best way to do this from the server-side?

**Edit** : When I say "Best" I mean most efficient and adhering to "best practices". My method doesn't work so well when it's put onto an authenticated IIS. I'm having trouble authenticating. I thought that doing

```
WebClient oClient = new WebClient();
oClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
oClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
String sData = oClient.DownloadString(sURL);
```

would work but i get a 401 error. Does anybody have any alternatives?

Cheers

Gordon

Comment: Best way for what? Performance? Maintainability? Readability? Something else?

Comment: Are you going to be getting html from a remote site or app domain?  Or are you planning on grabbing HTML from the same site/app?

Comment: Best for performance + maintainability, sorry..

Comment: I'll be reading from current site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without asking any questions about the reasoning behind fetching html via a webrequest from the same application serving the contents of the include, i would wrap the functionality in a WebUserControl. Something along the lines of:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class HtmlFetcher : UserControl
{
    //configure this somewhere else in the real world, web.config maybe
    private const string ServiceUrl = "http://localhost:666/";

    public string HtmlPath { get; set; }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        string outputText = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            outputText = new WebClient().DownloadString(string.Format("{0}{1}", ServiceUrl, HtmlPath));

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Handle that error;
        }
        output.Write(outputText);
    }
}
```

This is how you would add it to your page:

```
<%@ Register src="HtmlFetcher.ascx" tagname="HtmlFetcher" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<uc1:HtmlFetcher ID="HtmlFetcher1" HtmlPath="some-test-file.html" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you will get the data in the string lcHtml then use it as you want

```
 // *** Establish the request
    string lcUrl = "http://yourURL";
HttpWebRequest loHttp =
         (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(lcUrl);

    // *** Set properties
    loHttp.Timeout = 10000;     // 10 secs
    loHttp.UserAgent = "Code Sample Web Client";

    // *** Retrieve request info headers
    HttpWebResponse loWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) loHttp.GetResponse();

    Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);  // Windows default Code Page

    StreamReader loResponseStream =
       new StreamReader(loWebResponse.GetResponseStream(),enc);

    string lcHtml = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

    loWebResponse.Close();
    loResponseStream.Close();
```

Comment: how is this different to using WebClient (other than it's more code)

Answer (score 0):

You can use server side code blocks into your aspx with `<% %>`.

Try this:

```
<% new WebClient().DownloadString("http://localhost:666/" +sPage1URL) %>
```

Comment: And if an exception is thrown by `WebClient`, poof, there goes the page.